# Why Illustrator convert my paths into groups when exporting to SVG?

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I am using SVGs to configure avatars in a website. The IDs of the layers are used to change properties like fill, stroke or display, so the IDs must be well defined.

I have a problem with the last model. When I export it from Adobe Illustrator CC to SVG 1.1, some paths are automatically converted to a group with the path inside. The group has the ID instead the path.

It could be something with the Illustrator version, I have made the same process with other files and they are exported just fine.

This is what I was expecting to export:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="8 -9 640.6 640.6" enable-background="new 8 -9 640.6 640.6" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="chica">
        <g id="peinados">
            <g id="pelo15">
                    <path id="colorpelo" fill="#895C38" d="M258.6,245.7c-..."/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And this is what happens (Illustrator place the path with the ID "colorpelo_55_" inside a group and gives the group the ID):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="8 -9 640.6 640.6" enable-background="new 8 -9 640.6 640.6" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="chica">
        <g id="peinados">
            <g id="pelo15">
                <g id="colorpelo_55_">
                    <path fill="#895C38" d="M258.6,245.7c-..."/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it without doing it manually? (There are hundreds of layer's names to change).

Thank you!

Downloadable files:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ztkXVjbqvQmh77dLTAQM7NGwPfUHsUJd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it was about a calligraphic brush applied (it couldn't be be seen, but it was there). If somebody is interested in the complete answer, check this link:
https://forums.adobe.com/message/10886713